# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

Tags: java, multithreading, jodatime, noclassdeffounderror

When I'm retrieve data from Data Base ,seems there is no issues.But when I generate jasper reports its giving below Exception.This working for MySQL,but not working for MS-SQL.Requirement is MS-SQL. Please help me some one.Why we are getting commonly like this Excepton:-

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsBundle.addFunctionClass(FunctionsBundle.java:84)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsBundle.<init>(FunctionsBundle.java:54)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsRegistryFactory.createRegistry(FunctionsRegistryFactory.java:76)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:239)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:214)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on when you are getting this exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167559/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-joda-time-readabl)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have below dependency in your `classpath`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.8<version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add library jar (joda-time),
link-download https://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/2.4/