# In Hive: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, brickhouse

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167559/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-joda-time-readabl), but the answers don't help me.

I have added the necessary jar file `joda-time-2.2.jar` using the full path to the file. This file is needed by a function in Hive. Then trying to use a function in Hive I receive the error in the title.

I receive the error despite the jar is added like:

```
add jar /path/to/the/scripts/joda-time-2.2.jar;

hive> list jars;
/path/te/the/scripts/joda-time-2.2.jar
```

**Strangely** sometimes this error does not occur, so that I can execute the function successfully. But this error occurs mostly so that I am thrown out of hive with the error message.

I have tried different versions of the `joda-time-2.2.jar` file but no success.

Can someone help me?

P.S.: 
The lib I am using is [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Downloads). The full code is:

```
add jar /path/te/the/scripts/brickhouse-0.6.0-sources.jar;
add jar /path/te/the/scripts/joda-time-2.2.jar

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION from_json AS 'brickhouse.udf.json.FromJsonUDF';

select from_json('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":[["0","1","nnn"],["1","3","mmm"],["1","3","ggg"],["1","5","kkk"],["4","5","ppp"]]}', 'map<string,string>') from my_table;
```

Comment: You mention a function - is this a function you wrote and want to be able to run anytime in a Hive query? Is the jar for that function also being added when you add the joda-time jar?

Comment: @djmdata Hello, I am using the `brickhouse` library. I have editted the question. As I sain, very strangely this error sometimes doesn't occur, but occurs most of the time.

Answer (score -2):

You should add your jars like this :

add jar /path/te/the/scripts/joda-time-2.2.jar;

add jar /path/te/the/scripts/brickhouse-0.6.0-sources.jar;

Comment: How is this different from what OP is currently doing?

Comment: brickhouse-0.6.0-sources.jar depends on joda-time-2.2.jar

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to add that explanation.